# Get entries in intersection table based on key

Tags: java, hibernate

I have three tables:

```
offers; offer_groups; offer_group_members.
```

The `offers` and `offer_groups` tables are mapped with hibernate (see below).

In `offer_group_members`, I store to which group the offers belong (offer primary key, offer group primary key).

I am kinda new to hibernate so my question is: **How can I get all the `OfferGroups` from the `OFFER_GROUP_MEMBERS` table based on the Offer key?**

I tried something like this:

```
Criteria crit;
crit = getSession().createCriteria(Offer.class);
crit = crit.createCriteria("offerGroups");
crit.add(eq("key", offerKey));
```

---

Here are the mappings:

for offer:

```
    <composite-id name="comp_id"
        class="com.infonova.psm.hibernate.prodsrv.OfferPK">
        <key-property name="key" column="KEY"
            type="java.lang.String" length="128">
        </key-property>
    </composite-id>
```

for offer_group_key:

```
    <id name="key" type="java.lang.String" column="KEY" length="128">
        <generator class="assigned"/>
    </id>`
```

for offer_group_key:

```
        <set name="offers" table="OFFER_GROUP_MEMBERS" lazy="true" inverse="false"
        cascade="none">
        <key>
            <column name="OFFER_GROUP_KEY"/>
        </key>
        <many-to-many class="Offer">
            <column name="OFFER_KEY"/>
        </many-to-many>
    </set>
```

for offer:

```
        <set name="offerGroups" table="OFFER_GROUP_MEMBERS"
        inverse="true" lazy="true" cascade="none">
        <key>
            <column name="OFFER_KEY" />
        </key>
        <many-to-many
            class="OfferGroup">
            <column name="OFFER_GROUP_KEY" />
        </many-to-many>
    </set>
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier if you showed us the entities, since it's on them that HQL and criteria queries work.

Anyway, in HQL:

```
select og from Offer o
inner join o.offerGroups og
where o.key = :key
```

And in Criteria, unfortunately, IIRC, all you can do is select the root entity or scalars, so it's hard to do this without having a bidirectionall association. If you had a bidirectional association, you could do

```
Criteria c = session.createCriteria(OfferGroup.class, "og");
c.createAlias("og.offers", "o");
c.add(Restrictions.eq("o.key", key));
```

Since you don't have the bidirectional association, the only way that I know of is to do this:

```
Criteria c = session.createCriteria(OfferGroup.class, "og");
DetachedCriteria dc = DetachedCriteria.forClass(Offer.class, "o");
dc.createAlias("o.offerGroups", "og2");
dc.add(Restrictions.eq("o.key", key));
dc.setProjection(Projections.property("og2.id"));
c.add(Subqueries.propertyIn("og.id", dc));
```

which corresponds to this ugly HQL query:

```
select og from OggerGroup og
where og.id in (select og2.id from Offer o 
                inner join o.offerGroups og2 
                where o.key = :key)
```

For such simple static queries, I don't see any reason to go with Criteria rather than HQL.